# How to use string format to get %

Tags: python, string

I want to create a SQL statement in python 2.6 at runtime like below.

```
SQL = SELECT * FROM table1 where col1 LIKE '%somthing%'
```

the above one is running fine at database server, but i am facing problem while create this string in python. I am using string format %s to add variable. My python code look like below

```
var = "somthing"

SQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 where col1 LIKE '%%s%'" % var
```

i get the below traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 247
```

Comment: Don't do it like this - look up SQL Injection. Besides that, you should also really use new style string formatting (`str.format()`) over the old style (`%`).

Comment: @Bibhas: good thing this is Python then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use string formatting for SQL; use SQL parameters instead.

That said, you can escape `%` by doubling it to `%%`:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 where col1 LIKE '%%%s%%'" % var
```

Obligatory [XKCD reference](http://xkcd.com/327/) as customary warning.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `str.format`

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 where col1 LIKE '%{}%'".format(var)
```

Comment: Again, as another note, while this is right, **don't do this** - there are methods of doing this that protect against SQL injection, those are what you want. This does not.

Comment: we need to add 0 in `{}` like SQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 where col1 LIKE '%{0}%'".format(var) else getting `ValueError: zero length field name in format`

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao depends on your Python version. But you don't use string formatting for SQL anyway, as this and other answers say =)